# Boost Pointer PCL, update old pointer with new one and delete the new one

Tags: c++, boost

How might I be able to perform the above operation in Boost? I am using the PCL Library where I have a function as such:

```
void pcl_helper_functions::performRangeThresholding(
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr inputCloud,
    std::string axis, double startRange, double endRange
){
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr rangedCloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
    pcl::PassThrough<pcl::PointXYZRGB> passthroughFilter;
    passthroughFilter.setInputCloud(inputCloud);
    passthroughFilter.setFilterFieldName(axis);
    passthroughFilter.setFilterLimits(startRange, endRange);
    passthroughFilter.filter(*rangedCloud);
    inputCloud = rangedCloud;
    // return rangedCloud;
}
```

I want to set/copy inputCloud (the one that I passed in) to rangedCloud, then delete rangedCloud, so that the cloud that i pass into the function basically gets "updated"

Comment: I tried doing:
inputCloud.swap(rangedCloud);

But I get errors on later functions saying my point cloud is invalid

Comment: is this code not working already?

Comment: Considered using a reference? How would you do it without PCL? Why don't you return anything?

Comment: this code doesn't work. i get errors as mentioned in the comments

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what those errors are? Raaj, please delete your question and read the Stack Overflow posting guidelines before posting here again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass by reference:

```
void pcl_helper_functions::performRangeThresholding(
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr& inputCloud,
    std::string axis, double startRange, double endRange
){
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr rangedCloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
    pcl::PassThrough<pcl::PointXYZRGB> passthroughFilter;
    passthroughFilter.setInputCloud(inputCloud);
    passthroughFilter.setFilterFieldName(axis);
    passthroughFilter.setFilterLimits(startRange, endRange);
    passthroughFilter.filter(*rangedCloud);
    inputCloud = rangedCloud;
}
```

`inputCloud` will be deleted as soon as the last reference to it is release (it's a shared pointer).